# Retrieve firestore document array

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve an array of strings from a firestore document. I have tried the following code.

```
firestore.collection("Category").doc(category).get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        subcategory = (doc.data().Subcategories);
        array = subcategory.split(",");
        subcategoryDropdown[subcategoryDropdown.length] = new Option(array);     
    } else {
        alert("No such document!");
    } 
});
```

But when i run the code, it keeps bringing the array as one string separated by a comma.

**I am getting this: "obj1,obj2,obj3"** 
but **I'm trying to get it as an array such as ["Obj1","Obj2","Obj3"].**

I can't seem to split the array into an array with individual strings. The split command does not seem to work.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the input document, the values of the variables in the function that you know from logging or debugging, and the expected result, whatever that looks like (are you just looking at some HTML element?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, after looking through the console log, was that I was adding the array from the firestore document into another array.

Instead of doing var subcategoryArray = []; use an empty variable ie. var subcategory;